# Calculating the difference between multiple rows and one row containing the highest score in R

Tags: r

This is my first post, so forgive me if I have missed anything obvious from my description:

I have a dataframe with 50 rows of different meditation types. The columns NDM, CDM and ADM are categories of meditation. The numbers represent how many times people endorsed each meditation type as belonging to that category, with an Unsure option as well. The Max column is the highest score in that row.

I want to minus each score for each meditation category (Columns: NDM,CDM,ADM,Unsure) from the max score (Across cols for each row) to show the difference between the two, and then create a new column containing the difference for each meditation category.

Finally I want to calculate the mean score from these difference scores and add a column with that in.

| Meditation_Type | NDM | CDM | ADM | Unsure | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Meditation_1 | 12 | 63 | 8 | 9 | 63 |
| Meditation_2 | 5 | 75 | 9 | 3 | 75 |
| Meditation_3 | 20 | 45 | 26 | 1 | 45 |
| Meditation_4 | 6 | 72 | 12 | 2 | 72 |

I used the code below to calculate the max score across each row:

```
 Cat_Med[, "max"] <- apply(Cat_Med[, 1:4], 1, max)
```

I am stuck as how to move forwards from here.

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desired output is missing, but perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Meditation_Type    NDM     CDM     ADM     Unsure
Meditation_1    12  63  8   9
Meditation_2    5   75  9   3
Meditation_3    20  45  26  1
Meditation_4    6   72  12  2")

# make sure your data is in a data.tavle format.
# if it is nog, use setDT() to make it so

# melt to long format
DT.melt <- melt(DT, id.vars = "Meditation_Type")
# subytract each value from the maximum mediatation_type value
DT.melt[, value2 := max(value) - value, by = .(Meditation_Type)]
# cast to wide again
dcast(DT.melt, Meditation_Type ~ variable, value.var = c("value", "value2"))
#    Meditation_Type value_NDM value_CDM value_ADM value_Unsure value2_NDM value2_CDM value2_ADM value2_Unsure
# 1:    Meditation_1        12        63         8            9         51          0         55            54
# 2:    Meditation_2         5        75         9            3         70          0         66            72
# 3:    Meditation_3        20        45        26            1         25          0         19            44
# 4:    Meditation_4         6        72        12            2         66          0         60            70
```

Comment: Of course, desired output would make things clearer, I'll know for next time!

This looks good, and it is part of what I want to do. I also want to add another column giving the mean of those 4 new columns. 

Thanks for the first part.